# Compact Framework: A problem with reading a file

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I have a file stored in the same dir as my application. I try to load that file but I get an error (not found)

```
StreamReader str = new StreamReader("list.txt");
```

so, what path to the file I must declare to read it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In full framework I use:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string filename = Path.Combine(dir, "list.txt");
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename);
```

I don't know if in compact-framework this works, I cannot try now, sorry...

Answer (score 5):

Windows CE doesn't have the concept of "current directory". The OS tries to open \list.txt when passing "list.txt". You always have to specify the full path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

For the Compact Framework you can get the executing assembly location by using the code base path as follows:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
string filename = Path.Combine(dir, "list.txt");
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename);
```