# how to read .txt file into string windows 6 classic / windows CE, using vs2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, text-files, visual-studio-2005, windows-embedded-compact

iam creating an app for a handheld with windows embedded handheld 6.5, iam stuck with reading the content of text file and loading into a string. the file is tab delimeted with 3 columns (barcode, desc, price).the code will be executed on form load, i have written the below using c# on vb2005 releasing on windows 6 classic emulator, but the streamreader is always null.
i have written the below please any advices, i appreciate the help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileloc = "fileexample.txt";               
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileloc);
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();                   
}
```

Comment: Q: Have you tried [File.ReadAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: When i type File. I do not have the read all text option

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
File.ReadAllText("Full File Path");
```

and use the Full file path like **C:\fileexample.txt**

Answer (score 0):

OK:

> [How can I read all text when ReadAllText is unavailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934231/how-can-i-read-all-text-when-readalltext-is-unavailable)
>
> The compact-framework edition does not implement it. The .net version,
> however, is simply implemented like this:
>
> ```
> public static class File
> {
>     public static String ReadAllText(String path)
>     {
>         using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
>         {
>             return sr.ReadToEnd();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Note the second argument to StreamReader: Encoding.UTF8.

See also:

> [Compact Framework: A problem with reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975069/compact-framework-a-problem-with-reading-a-file)
>
> Windows CE doesn't have the concept of "current directory". The OS
> tries to open \list.txt when passing "list.txt". You always have to
> specify the full path to the file. ...
>
> In full framework I use:
>
> ```
> string dir = Path.GetDirectory(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
> string filename = Path.Combine(dir, "list.txt");
> StreamReader str = new StreamReader(filename);
> ```

STRONG SUGGESTIONS:

1. Specify an encoding (e.g. UTF8)
2. Set a breakpoint in this method and single-step through your code.

Comment: thank you when i compile iam getting the below error:

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ali\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\price_check_c\price_check_c\Form1.cs 19 20 price_check_c

Comment: "var" is a keyword that was introduced in C# 3.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var.  Your version is apparently too old.  Just substitute `StreamReader` for "var".  ALSO: please "upvote" and "accept" (the "check" icon) whenever you find a response helpful.

Comment: i have a motorola 3190 running on CE OS 5.2, iam using VS2005..dot net compact v2..iam aware that var and File.* are not all avilable in this version,  but i am searching an alternative i couldnt get one, i just need to import the contents of .txt file into a string or into an array in c#

Comment: The compiler version (e.g. MSVS 2005) is less relevant than your target platform.  Your target doesn't support "var" - the workaround is to explicitly give the type (StreamReader).  Your target *should* support [System.IO.StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader).   The code above *should* work if you just substitute "var".  Please post back specific messages if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found what I was looking for. I wanted to share so others would not suffer like I did:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
    string filename = Path.Combine(dir, "alisyd.txt");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
    string s = sr.ReadToEnd();          
}
```

Comment: Your response is substantially what I said in the first place: 1) you need to specify a fully qualified path, 2) You need sr.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 0):

```
string FilePath = "/"; //Root
string FileName = "MyFile.txt";
string MyString = "";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(FilePath + FileName), Encoding.Default, true);
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    MyString += sr.ReadLine();
}
sr.Dispose();
sr.Close();
```